# Impossible to link SDL/GLUT/GLM Ubuntu

Tags: c++11, opengl, gcc, sdl, glut

I actualy work on a openGL projet on my VM but i need openGL 4.5 so i have install ubuntu on my laptop with (GTX 870M) who is compatible 4.5 (i check with glxinfo). But my problem is after install gcc, build-essential, libglew-dev, freeglut3-dev, freeglut3  and SDL2. I can't make my projet i have error like undefined reference on « SDL_WasInit » , « glBegin », .... for all library installed...

i try with makefile like :

```
ifeq "$(shell uname)" "Darwin"
LIBGL=  -framework OpenGL
else
    LIBGL=  -lGLU -lGL
endif

CXXFLAGS += `pkg-config glew --cflags` `sdl2-config --cflags` -g -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config glew --libs` `sdl2-config --libs` $(LIBGL)

all : main.exe
run : main.exe
        ./main.exe
main.exe : main.cpp *.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o$@ main.cpp

sol : main_solution.exe
runs : main_solution.exe
        ./main_solution.exe
main_solution.exe : main_solution.cpp *.h
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ main_solution.cpp

clean :
        rm -f *.o *.exe
```

and with cmakefile like :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(src)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lGLEW -lm -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -Wall -g")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        """ALL SOURCE FILES"""")

add_executable(src ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

This projet (cmakefile and makefile) work fine on my virtual machine ...
I hope you can help me thx.

Comment: Those aren't ld flags, they're libs. And your libs should only get passed in the linking stage.

Comment: But it's work on my vm with thus configuration I don't understand why :/

Comment: Just because I could make a car with square wheels doesn't mean I should. You shouldn't put your libs with your ld flags; that's like putting your sources with your compiler flags.

Comment: Also, why are you using freeglut *and* SDL2?

Comment: It's for my school the teacher give me the projet but we need to freeglut and SDL who handle the opengl figure.

Comment: How I should use my library?

Comment: Well, SDL2 and Freeglut both handle very similar things. Usually you would just use SDL2 and GLEW.

Comment: I agree with you but how can I link this two library? In my cmakefile?

Comment: Well, you don't put your libs in your CXXFLAGS

Answer (score 0):

In CMake you use `target_link_libraries` to specify which libraries to use. In general you want to use `find_package(…)` to locate the configuration for a specific library, then use the variables introduced by it to link.

```
find_package(OpenGL)
add_executable(foo …)
target_link_libraries(foo ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} …)
```

You should look into the cmake modules that are used by `find_package` to see what the names of the variables they configure are.